# Distorted ziggeo recorder display

Tags: javascript, macos, video-streaming

[1 http://ahmadmilzam.com/tomodachi.jpg](http://ahmadmilzam.com/tomodachi.jpg)

Has anyone had encounter a problem like the image above?

Here's the code i'm using to embed the recorder into the page.

```
var monitorWidth = window.innerWidth,
    monitorHeight = window.innerHeight;

var embedding = ZiggeoApi.Embed.embed("#js-ziggeoRecorder", {
  id: 'recorder',
  width: Math.round(monitorWidth/2),
  recording_width: Math.round(monitorWidth/2),
  height: Math.round( (monitorWidth/2) * 0.5625 ),
  recording_height: Math.round( (monitorWidth/2) * 0.5625 ),
  disable_timer: true,
  disable_snapshots: true,
  disable_first_screen: true,
  immediate_playback: false
});
```

The recorder works fine with any modern browser on windows, chrome canary on windows and OSX, firefox, safari on OSX but not working with chrome on OSX.

Please let me know if any of you had encounter this before and have a solution for it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you share the specific monitorWidth and monitorHeight values on your computer?

Comment: @OliverFriedmann Hi Oliver, here is the width and height of my monitor : 1366x653

Comment: Works on my Chrome in OS-X in a minimal example html with your width / height. Can you confirm on your end that it doesn't work in a minimal example (without any additional js, css, etc.)?